# jQuery UI Tabs deselect event or save prev tab on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I love jQuery UI and use its "Tabs" on my sites for visual sliders as standart, but UI doesnt have an event for deselect.

What i mean:

I have an animation on tab `.show()`, but i want to have the **deselect** (but there is no **deselect event** on jQuery UI Tabs events) event animation on tab when it autorotates or by selecting another tab - current tab must do **deselect animation** and then show (with animation) selected tab.
Maybe somebody knows about this problem?
Thanks before!

Answer (score 0):

This logic can occur in the event for selecting. My example here is going to assume that you're linking the tab to the div by id, and that you've got a class called "selected" on the currently active tab. Change as necessary for your code.

```
$(".tabs li").click(function() {
  active_id = $(".tabs li.selected").attr(id);
  $this = $(this);
  $("div.tab-content#"+active_id).fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $this.addClass("selected");
    $("div.tab-content#"+$this.attr("id")).fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: thanx! but problem is about UI Tabs has own click event on tabs manage menu and do it in any case

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `fx` option?

In particular `$("#tabs").tabs("option", "fx", {opacity:'toggle'} )` or when you initialize it `$("#tabs").tabs({ fx: {opacity:'toggle'} })`